# How did Harry Potter treat his Aunt Petunia in her old age after he became successful given that he was mistreated as a boy?

Tags: harry-potter

Even though he was mistreated by his Aunt, the Aunt raised him up. He still owed some duty to his Aunt no matter how bad the mistreatment. Given that Harry is rich, he has the means to be kind. Did he repay his Aunt and the family with kindness even though the Aunt was quite mean to him as a boy? Did he take on the burden of looking after the aged Aunt and Uncle who raised him up when they needed help?